# deploy to docker , cannot load stylesheet and javascript

Tags: docker, nginx, flask

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    expose:
      - "8000"
    volumes:
      - /usr/src/app/web/project/static
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 2 -b :8000 project:app
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /www/static
    volumes_from:
      - web
    depends_on:
      - web

  data:
    image: postgres:9.6
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql
    command: "true"

  postgres:
    restart: always
    build: ./postgresql
    volumes_from:
      - data
    expose:
      - "5432"
```

When I deployed to docker container, the site has no style css, js loaded correctly, anyone please help ?

**UPDATED**

```
# Define the parameters for a specific virtual host/server
server {
    # Define the directory where the contents being requested are stored
    # root /usr/src/app/project/;

    # Define the default page that will be served If no page was requested
    # (ie. if www.ezloan.amkcambodia.com is requested)
    # index index.html;

    # Define the server name, IP address, and/or port of the server
    listen 80;
    # server_name xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa

    # Define the specified charset to the “Content-Type” response header field
    charset utf-8;

    # Configure NGINX to deliver static content from the specified folder
    location /static {
        alias /usr/src/app/web/project/static;
    }

    # Configure NGINX to reverse proxy HTTP requests to the upstream server (Gunicorn (WSGI server))
    location / {
        # Define the location of the proxy server to send the request to
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;

        # Redefine the header fields that NGINX sends to the upstream server
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # Define the maximum file size on file uploads
        client_max_body_size 5M;
        client_body_buffer_size 5M;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the content of `static` folder? does js reside in the static folder also or comes from the web?

Comment: I load it in template like this `<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap-select.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: when I access `http://0.0.0.0/static/css/bootstrap-select.min.css` is display 404 Not Found

Comment: yeah I know the `css` is not working... but what about the `js` files that does works? are they come from the local folder also?
usually `volumes` tag in docker is defined as `src(host):dest(guest)`

Comment: yes js not working as well, it in the static folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change the `volumes` directive on the `web` to

```
volumes:
   - /usr/src/app/web/project/static:<path of app on the container>
```

regard the Nginx

where the static files stored? in the `web` container or the `nginx`?
if they stored in the `nginx` you need to point the `alias` to the location on the nginx container, where you mount your nginx's volumes like

```
volumes:
    - /usr/src/app/web/project/static:/www/static
```

and in nginx conf use

```
location /static {
    alias /www/static;
}
```

if the static stored in the `web` container than `nginx` need to redirect the call to the web, thus `location /static` is not needed

Comment: I updated ngixn, please help to check, it is the problem of nginx?

Comment: @kn3l added my answer about the nginx conf